# Distinct and List of other column in postgresql

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am using postgres DB and i have table with two column `name` and `sal` .

```
   name       Sal
  Raunak     10000
  Raunak     5000
  Rahul      500
  Raunak     300
```

And i want

```
Raunak 10000,5000,300
Rahul  500
```

i am using JPA is there any way to get in JPA data

Answer (score 1):

You can use string_agg function to build a comma separated list of values:

```
select name, string_agg(sal::text, ',')
from t
group by name
```

You might want to consider `json_agg` instead of csv if your application can consume json data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the data type of the `sal` column, you can use `array_agg()` that returns an array of values. Not sure if JPA will let you access that properly though

```
select name, array_agg(sal) as sals
from the_table
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,  you want to get the result via below SQL statement:

```
SELECT
  name,
  string_agg (sal::varchar(22), ', ') as sals
FROM
  test
GROUP BY
  name;
```

Since it's postgresql related SQL,  we can't or hard to express it via common object query.  You can construct the above SQL via native query mode in your JPA code.

```
@Query(value = "<the above query>", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> query();
```

Comment: The cast can be simplified to `sal::text` no need to artificially restrict the length